# Go: dynamic struct composition

Tags: go, struct

I'm looking to understand which is the most suitable approach to solve the following problem.

I have a struct that represents the data to be serialised as part of a JSON response. A property on this struct `config` can be one of three possible structs, however, the only way I know to represent this is using the type `interface{}` and have the caller type assert the property.

```golang
type Response struct {
    Field1 string      `json:"field1"`
    Field2 int         `json:"field2"`
    Config interface{} `json:"config"`
}

type ConfigOne struct {
    SomeField string
}

type ConfigTwo struct {
    SomeField int
}

type ConfigThree struct {
    SomeField bool
}
```

Then I can have `New` style functions to create the right instance for me:

```golang
func NewConfigTwo() *Response {
    return &Response{
        Field1: "hello",
        Field2: 1,
        Config: ConfigTwo{
            SomeField: 22,
        },
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to represent a field with a enum like type of structs? Or is this as good as I can make it?

I'd appreciate any clarity or suggestions on how best to achieve this.

Comment: As far as serializing the Response into JSON this is as good as it gets. If you want to enforce "enum" like restriction to the field you could declare a non-empty interface and then have the members of the enum implement it, that way values of types that don't implement that interface won't be assignable to that field.

Comment: @mkopriva hmm interesting, I will try that out, thanks.

Comment: If you're interested you can see this approach being used even in the std lib. For example the [`ast.Expr` interface](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/ast/ast.go#L38-L42) and the [types that implement it.](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/go/ast/ast.go#L489-L514)

Comment: @mkopriva this is very useful actually, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you're trying to implement an algebraic data type here. To expand on @mkopriva's comment, take a look at this post: [Go and algebraic data types](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/go-and-algebraic-data-types/). Essentially you'll specify a non-empty interface such that all possible types implement a method and others don't satisfy the interface "by chance" (whereas every type implements `interface{}`) and then use type switches.

Something like (untested):

```
type Response struct {
    Field1 string      `json:"field1"`
    Field2 int         `json:"field2"`
    Config Configable  `json:"config"`
}

type Configable interface {
    isConfig()
}

type ConfigOne struct {
    SomeField string
}

func (ConfigOne) isConfig() {}

// ... and so on for other Config* types
```

Comment: @Adrian: yes, in this sense I don't believe my version is different from the original